# How to escape backslashes in querystring

Tags: asp.net, string, escaping, backslash, querystringparameter

I have an SqlDataSource that takes a value from querystring and bind it with a gridview. Everything works nicely unless the querystring value has a backslash in it. How do I escape the backslash?

Example:

www.example.com?id=testuser -> works.

www.example.com?id=test\user -> doesn't work even though "test\user" exists.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM User WHERE userID = @id">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" 
            QueryStringField="id" DbType="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTask" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>                
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitId" HeaderText="UnitId" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="UnitId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="UserName" />           
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i haven't used sqldatasource before, i hope it does something fancy with the parameters otherwise this is a sql injection disaster waiting to happen, just a heads up

Comment: @Daniel, to be honest, I don't know either. Can someone chime in?

Comment: To answer the SQL injection concerns, ASP.NET doesn't merely splice the parameter into the SQL statement; parameters are sent outside of the SQL statement. In addition, pages, by default, throw an error if they detect an attack; I don't know what detection techniques ASP.NET uses though.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is `%5C` in a query string.

Answer (score 2):

Try the built-in utility:

```
    String Url = @"www.example.com?id=test\user";

    Url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Url);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx

Hint:  There is also a UrlDecode function.

Comment: Isn't this more of a sql/c# problem? Since the @id gets passed in as a parameter, sql is unable to process the backslash properly. Does it matter if the url gets encoded and decoded before hand?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "www.example.com?id=test\user" is even running the page successfully? Slashes in URLs can cause the server to try to look for the wrong page in the wrong place.

You'd use Server.UrlEncode if you create the URL from another page/program; if you're creating it manually you should just encode it yourself (use John's suggestion of %5C).